# Incorporating ffmpeg in a bash script

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have a very large audio mp4 file that contains several songs.

I have generated a script which reads a text file with the times and the song names and successfully assigns starttime, endtime and songtitle in 3 variables. The script successfully echoes the variables and returns the following format:

```
00:00:00 00:10:15 Song1
00:10:15 00:14:20 Song2
```

and so on...

Now I am intending to use this script with `ffmpeg` and crop each part of the big file into smaller audio files.

The script thus, after feeding the variables in a `while` loop, it reaches to the command

```
ffmpeg -ss $START -t $END -i ${1} -acodec copy $SONGNAME.mp4
```

Once I run the script, the first two songs are cropped, but then the whole process stops with

```
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
error parsing debug value
debug=0
```

I checked the generated files and they play ok, but there is no way for me to know why the script stopped there and did no proceed to the rest of the file (considering that when in the script I replace `ffmpeg` with `echo`, the script echoes the variables flawlessly).

In other words I don't know if there is a problem in my script, `ffmpeg`, or the source music file.

Comment: Can you manually run that command on the third song in the file? What is the name of the third song? Does it perhaps contain a space?

Comment: Yes it does contain a space!

Comment: So enclose your variables in double quotes, like this `"$SONGNAME.mp4"`

Comment: Yup, your command is being parsed as `ffmpeg ... -acodec copy first_word second_word.mp4` and ffmpeg is getting confused about what you want to do.

Comment: You should show your script.

Answer (score 4):

In this case I would add the argument `-nostdin` to `ffmpeg`.